Wishart distribution implementation with positive semidefinite scale matrix
The built-in Mathematica function WishartMatrixDistribution[\[Nu],\[CapitalSigma]]  requires a positive definite (PD) scale matrix \[CapitalSigma]. However, this source says that the Wishart "...is a probability distribution on the set of  p×p symmetric non-negative definite random matrices". My understanding is that "non-negative definite" means "positive semidefinite" (PSD). The same source then refers to R's rWishart function that can generate Wishart-distributed variates. The help for rWishart says, however, that the scale matrix must be PD.
Please forgive my confusion, I have just started digging myself into the topic so most likely I am missing something. What I am interested is in generating Wishart-distributed PSD matrices with Mathematica. Would I get those from a call to RandomVariate[WishartMatrixDistribution[...]] if I parametrise the Wishart with a PD scale matrix? If yes, what sort of rank deficiency can I expect from the PSD variates? And if not, is there an implementation of the Wishart with a PSD (rather than PD) scale matrix, assuming it's not a mathematical impossibility/nonsense?
I apologise in advance if this question is not appropriate here -- the reason for my posting is that I need to implement this stuff in Mathematica. But if you can point me to an appropriate math or stats discussion group, I would be very grateful. Thank you.

I hope some experts will answer, but as far as I understand from Probability density function section of Wikipedia, you might be confusing the matrices $X$ with $V$ described there.

I noticed that your  question touches on an important distinction between positive definite (PD) and positive semidefinite (PSD) matrices in the context of the Wishart distribution,Here's how to generate Wishart-distributed matrices:
(* Define parameters *)
ν = 5; (* degrees of freedom *)
Σ = {{2, 1}, {1, 2}}; (* PD scale matrix *)

(* Generate a Wishart-distributed random matrix *)
wishartSample = RandomVariate[WishartMatrixDistribution[ν, Σ]]

(* Check if the generated matrix is PSD *)
Eigenvalues[wishartSample]



You didn't answer my question and the text reads like as if it had been generated by an LLM.
